# numpy matrix trace behaviour

Tags: numpy, matrix

If X is a NumPy `matrix` object, why does `np.trace(X)` return a scalar (as expected) but `X.trace()` return a `1x1` `matrix` object?

```
>>> X = np.matrix([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
>>> np.trace(X)
5
>>> X.trace()
matrix([[5]])   # Why not just 5, which would be more useful?
```

I'm using NumPy 1.7.1, but don't see anything in the release notes of 1.8 to suggest anything's changed.

Answer (score 2):

Because `X.trace` is coded that way!  The `matrix` documentation says:

> A matrix is a specialized 2-D array that retains its 2-D nature
>       through operations.

`np.trace` is coded as (using `ndarray.trace`):

```
return asarray(a).trace(offset, axis1, axis2, dtype, out)
```

It's harder to follow how the matrix trace is evaluated.  But looking at https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/matrixlib/defmatrix.py

I suspect it is equivalent to:

```
np.asmatrix(X.A.trace())
```

In that same file, `sum` is defined as:

```
return N.ndarray.sum(self, axis, dtype, out, keepdims=True)._collapse(axis)
```

`mean`, `prod` etc do the same.  `_collapse` returns a scalar if `axis` is `None`.  There isn't an explicit definition for a matrix `trace`, so it probably uses `__array_finalize__`.  In other words, `trace` returns the default `matrix` type.

Several constructs that return the scalar are:

```
X.A.trace()
X.diagonal().sum()
X.trace()._collapse(None)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def __array_finalize__(self, obj):
    self._getitem = False
    if (isinstance(obj, matrix) and obj._getitem): return
    ndim = self.ndim
    if (ndim == 2):
        return
    if (ndim > 2):
        newshape = tuple([x for x in self.shape if x > 1])
        ndim = len(newshape)
        if ndim == 2:
            self.shape = newshape
            return
        elif (ndim > 2):
            raise ValueError("shape too large to be a matrix.")
    else:
        newshape = self.shape
    if ndim == 0:
        self.shape = (1, 1)
    elif ndim == 1:
        self.shape = (1, newshape[0])
    return
```

This is from the matrix definition, subclassing ndarray. The trace function is not changed so it is actually the same function getting called.

This function is getting called every time a matrix object is created. The problem is that if ndims is less than 2, it is forced to be larger.

Then here comes some educated guess work, which i think should be true, but i'm not familiar enough with numpy codebase to figure it out exactly.

- np.trace and ndarray.trace are two different functions.

  - np.trace is defined in "core/fromnumeric.py"
  - ndarray.trace is defined in "core/src/multiarray/methods.c or calculation.c"
- np.trace converts the object to a ndarray
- ndarray.trace will try to keep the object as the subclassed object.

  - Unsure about this, i did not understand squat of that code tbh

both trace functions, will keep the result as an array object (subclassed or not). If it's a single value, it will return that single value, or else it returns the array object.

Since the result is kept as a matrix object, it will be forced to be two dimensional by the function above here. And because of this, it will not be returned as a single value, but as the matrix object.

This conclusion is further backed up by editing the `_array_finalize__` function like this:

```
def __array_finalize__(self, obj):
    self._getitem = False
    if (isinstance(obj, matrix) and obj._getitem): return
    ndim = self.ndim
    if (ndim == 2):
        return
    if (ndim > 2):
        newshape = tuple([x for x in self.shape if x > 1])
        ndim = len(newshape)
        if ndim == 2:
            self.shape = newshape
            return
        elif (ndim > 2):
            raise ValueError("shape too large to be a matrix.")
    else:
        newshape = self.shape
    return
    if ndim == 0:

        self.shape = (1, 1)
    elif ndim == 1:

        self.shape = (1, newshape[0])
    return
```

notice the new `return` before the last if-else check. Now the result of X.trace() is a single value.

**THIS IS NOT A FIX, revert the change if you try this yourself.**
They have good reasons for doing this

`np.trace`does not have this problems since it convert's it to an array object directly.

The code for `np.trace` is (without the docstring):

```
def trace(a, offset=0, axis1=0, axis2=1, dtype=None, out=None):

    return asarray(a).trace(offset, axis1, axis2, dtype, out)
```

From the docstring of `asarray`

> Array interpretation of `a`.  No copy is performed if the input
>           is already an ndarray.  **If `a` is a subclass of ndarray, a base
>           class ndarray is returned**.

Comment: Thanks for this - that's pretty comprehensive. Since there doesn't seem to be any good reason for numpy.matrix.trace() to return a matrix, I'll raise it as a bug and see what the numpy folk think.